# Android-apt plugin is incompatible. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: android

I didn't find a working solution for my problem. Can anybody look at my code and tell me what  should I change. Changing compile to implementatino doesn't work. I already tried to clear, rebuild and invalidate. I also tried to change version of realm to the greatest, but then I am getting erron connected to app.

**app/build.grade**

```
    plugins {
    id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.2.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.storware.kodo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-2.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/edm.jar')
    compile files('libs/knox.jar')
    compile files('libs/license.jar')
    compile files('libs/rc.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0' // optional

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'

    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'

    compile 'info.guardianproject.iocipher:IOCipherStandalone:0.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mobilesolutionworks:works-util:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'

    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20090211'

}
```

**build.grade**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason you are using Retrolamda with java 8?

Comment: Actually I didn't develop this project from the scratch, I am just supporting it, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same problem.
Resolved it by updating to the latest  realm-gradle-plugin

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
```

Hope this helps.